# How to increase adjacent HTML element height based current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to increase the height of the adjacent element based on the height of the current element.

I have two droppable buckets in my page and we can drop different sizes of images into these buckets.

If we drop 100px height image to bucketOne I want to increase the bucketTwo height to 100px to match it to the bucketOne height.

Below is my HTML and css code.

Please help me!

Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="row row-bucket">
    <div id="bucketOne" class="col-md-6 drop-bucket" droppable="true">
    </div>
    <div id="bucketTwo" class="col-md-6 drop-bucket" droppable="true">
    <div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-bucket{
   background-color: #ffffff;
   height: auto;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 2px;;
}

.drop-bucket{
   border-style: dotted;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   border-width: 2px;
   min-height: 50px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `$('#bucketTwo').height($('#bucketOne').height());`

Comment: you'll need more information to make this an answerable post. for example: what language, what you've tried and why you can't easily find this answer on google or this site already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code to know whether the image is dropped and the size of the image, then you can set the height of the other one.

Does this help?